# Export database tables to .xlsx file

Tags: postgresql

I want to export my database tables to an Excel 2007 spreadsheet using servlets. Can anybody help me on this? I use Postgres SQL as back end.

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot use CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be looking for an [API to write MS Office files](http://poi.apache.org/). Since you note servlets, I assume you are coding in Java.